# How to avoid a repetitive code when creating similar dropdown lists?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Below is the code where i created a drop down list, i am able to retrieve data from MySQL but i have to repeat the option step for every field, how can I setup a code for the drop down so i can just shorten to call it once in selection list, like in a for loop..also how do i create a error message to display if there is no selection, and if i select a data from the list it stores in the database

```
 <form action="sign.php" method="post">
 <label for="employee_name">Employee name</label>
 <select name = "employee_name">
 <option value=""> -----------Select----------- </option> 
 <?php
 $stmt = $pdo->prepare('Select name from people');
 $stmt->execute();
 while($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
 echo '<option>'.$row['name'].'</option>';
 }
 ?>
 </select> 
 <label for="manager">manager</label>
 <select name = "manager">
 <option value=""> -----------Select----------- </option> 
 <?php
 $stmt = $pdo->prepare('Select name from people');
 $stmt->execute();
 while($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
 echo '<option>'.$row['name'].'</option>';
 }
 ?>
 </select> 
 <label for="senior">Senior</label>
 <select name = "Senior">
 <option value=""> -----------Select----------- </option> 
 <?php
 $stmt = $pdo->prepare('Select name from people');
 $stmt->execute();
 while($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
 echo '<option>'.$row['name'].'</option>';
 }
 ?>
 </select> 
 <input type="submit" name="register" value=" Click to Add"></button>
 </form>
```

Comment: Sharpen your logical thinking :) No, I mean one coder needs to know how to make a good concept.

Answer (score 0):

Use array and run query once to set options in array.

```
<?php
$optionArray = array();
 $stmt = $pdo->prepare('Select name from people');
 $stmt->execute();
 while($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    $optionArray[] = '<option value="'.$row['name'].'">'.$row['name'].'</option>';
 }
 ?>

<form action="sign.php" method="post">
 <label for="employee_name">Employee name</label>
 <select name = "employee_name">
 <option value=""> -----------Select----------- </option> 
 <?php
foreach($optionArray as $row)
{
    echo $row;
}
 ?>
 </select>
```

Comment: PDO is smarter than old mysql ext, and let you avoid manual array creation. Check [fetchAll() method](https://phpdelusions.net/pdo#fetchall)

Answer (score 0):

> how can I setup a code for the drop down so i can just shorten to call it once in selection list, like in a for loop.

Just create a loop. though it should be foreach, not for.

First collect your data,

```
$people = $pdo->query('Select name from people order by name')->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_COLUMN);
$sections = [
    'employee_name' => 'Employee name',
    'manager'       => 'Manager',
    'senior'        => 'Senior',
];
```

and then loop it over

```
<form action="sign.php" method="post">
<?php foreach ($sections as $label => $caption): ?>
    <label for="<?=$label?>"><?=$caption?></label>
    <select name = "<?=$label?>">
        <option value=""> -----------Select----------- </option> 
        <?php foreach ($people as $name): ?>
            <option><?=$name?></option>
        <?php endforeach ?>
    </select> 
<?php endforeach ?>
<input type="submit" name="register" value=" Click to Add"></button>
</form>
```

Answer (score -1):

Instead of repeating this every time you can create a method which performs the same task.

```
<label for="employee_name">Employee name</label>
<select name = "employee_name">
<option value=""> -----------Select----------- </option> 
   <?=loadOptions('name','people');?> <!--shortcut way to echo in php-->
</select>

<?php 
function loadOptions($field,$table){
   $stmt = $pdo->prepare('Select '.$field.' from '.$table);
   $stmt->execute();
   $options='';
   while($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
      $options .= '<option>'.$row['name'].'</option>';
   }
   return $options;
}
?>
```

Comment: how do i add a message saying that the selection cannot be empty or it is required if i did not select an option from the list

Comment: @Deep13 that's a different question and you should ask it in a different post

Comment: you can specify the required attribute in the <select required> tag for HTML5 default error message OR you have to create your own script for the following element

Comment: no i did not down vote, thats the guy with no common sense

Comment: :) for validation you can use jquery validation plugin which eases your work at free of cost... check this here -->> https://jqueryvalidation.org/